# Updating remote Function App Application Settings in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, application-settings

I am currently writing a scheduled Function App that in part will need to update an Application Setting of a different Function App on which I have given the Service Principal access. The Function App that I need to update is hosted within the same App Service Plan.

I understand that I can achieve this through Powershell using the [az functionapp config appsettings set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set) cmdlet but I wanted to know if this is possible in C#

Comment: Have you considered other ways to store and read the data you have in configuration? The reason you are struggling with this is that you generally shouldn't need to do it, so there is no straightforward way. The first thing that comes to mind is to have your setting be a keyvault reference, then you can update the keyvault secret from c# and it will flow automatically.

Comment: I am trying to update a current key vault reference as the secret has been updated as part of a storage account key rotation process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is possible using the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent?view=azure-dotnet) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent?view=azure-dotnet) extension libraries which are wrappers around the REST calls.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Azure_Storage_Account_Key_Rotation
{
    internal async Task UpdateApplicationSetting(string appServiceResourceGroupName, string appServiceName, string appSettingName, string appSettingValue)
    {
        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"),
                                                                                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                                                                                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID"),
                                                                                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                    .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                    .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                    .Build();

        WebSiteManagementClient webSiteManagementClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(restClient) { SubscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID") };

        var appServiceSettings = await webSiteManagementClient.WebApps.ListApplicationSettingsAsync(appServiceResourceGroupName, appServiceName);

        if (appServiceSettings.Properties.ContainsKey(appSettingName))
        {
            appServiceSettings.Properties[appSettingName] = appSettingValue;
            await webSiteManagementClient.WebApps.UpdateApplicationSettingsAsync(appServiceResourceGroupName, appServiceName, appServiceSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Azure CLI` or `Azure PowerShell Module` is nothing more than a way to execute [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/). So you can call REST API directly using C# HttpClient.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) you can check how to call REST API endpoints using postman (i.e. how to get tokens etc.) To change appsetting you need this endpoint [Web Apps - Create Or Update Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration) -> **properties.appSettings**.